# Best place to store the password for connecting to database

Tags: sql-server, database, passwords

This old chestnut again, there seems to be so many posts about this but I'm wondering if anything has changed or how do you do it?
I have multiple clients on a web server accessing their own database. What is the latest advice on storing their passwords.
I've seen:
`web.config`
File away from the root of the web server 
`Com object/dll`
`Registry`
`file saved out of the web root`

All seem to have advantages and disadvantages. 
I'm just wondering what seems to be the most followed example

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not storing passwords anywhere on the server. I'd use integrated security where ever possible, and even then encrypt the connection strings in web.config and tie down with file permissions.

Comment: if you encrypt the connection strings do you not have to store the decryption keys somewhere so you can decrypt and then connect to the DB?